# Xamarin forms FFImageLoading CornersTranformation

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I have a UI design like at following image. I'm using FFImageLoading plugin and Corner Transformations but I could not cut image form top to bottom of image. How can I do this ?

I'm trying following code but it's not working.

```
var imgProd = new CachedImage { Source = temp.imgSource, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, Margin = 0, DownsampleHeight = vm.featureStackHeight, DownsampleToViewSize = true, Aspect = Aspect.Fill};
    imgProd.Transformations.Add(new CornersTransformation { CornersTransformType = CornerTransformType.TopLeftCut | ,TopLeftCornerSize=50 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following works in xaml:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source ="{Binding ImageFile}"
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
        <fftransformations:CornersTransformation 
             CornersTransformType="TopLeftCut" 
             TopLeftCornerSize="50" />
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```